# Python BeautifulSoup not processing entire page

Tags: python, dom, beautifulsoup, href, urllib2

I'm writing this nice tool which will return every link on a web page.
I tried to do this with help from another 'stackoverflow' question and got this code meanwhile:

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request(url)

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link['href']
```

I thought that it worked, but unfortunately I saw that a lot of links are missing,
I believe it's because some of the links are generated when DOM comes to action and BeautifulSoup does not takes it in consideration.

Comment: BeautifulSoup cannot execute JavaScript; it is not a browser. Use an actual browser (even one that is not displaying anything, a headless browser) to do so and get a full DOM. Selenium or PhantomJS or similar tools can all do that for you, driven by Python.

Comment: Thank you, Do you have any code sample that can give me a lead?